# Как в <filesystem> проверить, что путь заканчивается на /?

Tags: c++, файловая-система

Как в `<filesystem>` проверить, что путь заканчивается на `/` (или подобный символ), чтобы добавить `index.html`? `!has_extension()` не катит, потому что для файлов без расширения (`plain`, а не `plain.txt`) тоже будет добавлять.

Comment: Так вроде добавление имени к пути через оператор `/` само смотрит, есть ли сепаратор?

Comment: @Harry да, но мне нужно не добавить, а именно проверить, в пути последний символ сепаратор или нет. Так в парсере HTTP написано. Пока что решил это через `has_filename()`

Answer (score 1):

Вам достаточно проверки `has_filename`, чтобы убедиться, что на конце пути есть файл. Т.е. Ваша проверка будет выглядеть так: `!has_filename()`

Answer (score 0):

```
std::experimental::filesystem::path my_path = "/media/";

if (my_path.string().back() == '/')
    std::cout << "ends with /" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "not ends with /" << std::endl;
```